# Bootstraping an application, is triggers a good idea?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, postgresql

I'm a building an internal webb application for components of building parts. I have table with projects which is tied to some other tables. When a user creates a new project, I want to  "bootstrap" the project with a default categorization schema, which the user then can modify for his/her project. So I need to do some copy from a default schema and tie it to the users project.

I'm running NodeJS on backend, AngularJS on frontend and postgres as db. Where is the best way to put this logic? Either I use triggers on the db. The trigger is activated when a new post is made to the project table. Or, I'll do it with complicated queries in Node. Or is there some other way? Is there a best practice? It's probably "easier" to do a trigger. But I worry about the maintenance and testing of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue that you have is related to the state of the database, you should solve it inside the database. There are basically two ways of solving this:

1. Revoke the insert privilege on the project table. Create a function new_project() that has parameters for all the required initial state of the project. Inside that function you create schema, do some copying, setup privileges and populate the tables with the parameter values.
2. Revoke the insert privilege on the project table. Create a view that has all required columns from all relevant tables to make a valid initial project and create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the views. In the trigger function you perform all the required steps as above.

Debugging code on PostgreSQL is not very advanced but whether or not you place you code in PostgreSQL or on the application side, you will have the same issues. The advantage of PostgreSQL is that the bug - if any - is never far away from where you code operates.